# Referencing variables in an SCSS root file from a module file

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm very new to SCSS so I'm still learning the basics.

I'm simply wondering if you can access variables and mixins in a parent file from a child module. It's kind of hard to put into words so I'll give an example below..

*File: app.scss*

```
@use base;

$main_color: red;
```

*File: _base.scss*

```
@use app;

body {
   color: app.main_color;
}
```

The idea is that you could have a root file with a bunch of base styles that the imported modules could reference... is this a thing? If so how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change _base.scss in this way:

```
@import "app";

body {
   color: $main_color;
}
```